# How to configure logout on a webpage that has been authorized after a successful Active Directory authentication?

Tags: perl

How to configure logout on a webpage that has been authorized after a successful Active Directory authentication?

Here is the code:

```
!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use Authen::Simple::ActiveDirectory;
use Authen::Simple;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

read(STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

@pairs = split(/&/, $FormData);

foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
    # Separate the name and value:
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);

    # Convert + signs to spaces:
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;

    # Convert hex pairs (%HH) to ASCII characters:
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

    # Store values in a hash called %FORM:
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
}

$username=$FORM{'user'};
$password=$FORM{'pswd'};
$result;

my $ad = Authen::Simple::ActiveDirectory->new(
    host => 'XXXXX.XXXX',
    principal => 'XXX.XXXX',
);

if ( $ad->authenticate( $username , $password ) ) {
    $result="successfull";
    Page-X();
}
else
{
    $result="unsuccessfull";
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    print " \n";
    print "Authentication";
    print "\n";
    print "\n";
    print "Check Logins";
    print "\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

If the user got authenticated successfully, then he will be getting a page-X.
Now, how can i have him logout from page-X?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Regards,
Chandu

Answer (score 0):

Are you maintaining legacy code or writing new software?

The `use CGI;` line was historically important to the internet but should not be used anymore on new sotftware. Yet you are not even using CGI anyway as you are reading and parsing the STDIN by hand. You should not be doing that.

I recommend reading the amazing [Catalyst Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial::01_Intro) to get a glance on how Web Development has evolved since 1994.

The Catalyst Plugin for Active Directory (and Apple, Zimbra, whatever LDAP based system) is the [Catalyst::Authentication::Store::LDAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Authentication::Store::LDAP)

I really suggest following the Tutorial first (which has support for authentication and authorization) and only after having your initial application working add support for MS AD authentication, it will work almost as a drop in replacement.

The effort of studying the Tutorial will payoff in less than 3 days.

Comment: Are you maintaining legacy code or writing new software?  -> I'm just developing a small tool that we use internally/in intranet. I just got struck at configuring logout....

Comment: So new software it is.